# is it possible to return sequential responses from asp.net web api or WCF or Restful Services?

Tags: rest, wcf, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

is it possible to return multiple sequential responses with asp.net web api or WCF or any other possible REST methodologies?

So basically there will be only 1 request to a web api function and web api will return a response then couple of seconds later another response and another...

In my web api method, I'm calling lots of other functions and everytime a function completed I want to return a response and continue to the next one and return a response and continue to the next until to the end. So the client side will be informed the stage of the server side.

Note that I'm not asking something like a chat application.

Comment: Check out SignalR. This appears to be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What is the ultimate goal you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Thanks for this, I'm trying to show to the user on client side the status of his request. So basically when user clicks a button, I will show a progress bar and show exactly what is happening and what's done on the server side.

Comment: are you using angular4?

Comment: yes correct, I'll use Angular4 and send 1 request and trying to listen the responses from the server side. But not sure how I can do this in both, Angular and web api.

Comment: looks like SignalR might be a solution what I'm trying to achieve as suggested by Nkosi. But if there is any other suggestion, I would be appreciated as well

Comment: @junky, While you say you are not asking for something like a chart application you do however want real time feed back from the server. Which is why I suggested SignalR

Answer (score 0):

[Learn About ASP.NET SignalR](http://www.asp.net/signalr)

> ASP.NET SignalR is a new library for ASP.NET developers that makes
>   developing real-time web functionality easy. SignalR allows
>   bi-directional communication between server and client. Servers can
>   now push content to connected clients instantly as it becomes
>   available. SignalR supports Web Sockets, and falls back to other
>   compatible techniques for older browsers. SignalR includes APIs for
>   connection management (for instance, connect and disconnect events),
>   grouping connections, and authorization.

For your scenario after the user clicks the button the action while performing its process would pass upates back to the client showing the progress of what is happening and what's done on the server side

It was indicated in the comments that the client is JS based.

Here is a [ASP.NET SignalR Hubs API Guide - JavaScript Client](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client) to get started.